# Why does my virtual machine (Debian on Proxmox) not respond to a TCP SYN of another VM even though it arrives?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, tcp, proxmox

I got a very strange problem and I am out of ideas to solve it. I hope anyone over here has a helpful idea.

Some info about the virtual machines:

- VM0: Debian 10 - 192.168.10.102 [+ 2 more interfaces]
- VM1: Debian 10 - 192.168.10.103
- Both are virtualized using proxmox (the proxmox firewall for both is not online, the cluster firewall allows all traffic in the local network)
- They are directly connected via a bridge interface
- Both machines have correct Routes (192.168.10.0/24 via the correct bridge and no route with a higher prevalence pointing at wrong places)
- Both machines have the correct entry for the other one in their ARP table
- Both machines have empty iptables rules and no other firewall configured

Behaviour when connecting from VM0 to VM1:

- VM0:[random high port] -> VM1:1234 is working properly via TCP
- SSH connections to VM1 can be made

Behaviour when connecting from VM1 to VM0:

- VM1:[random high port] -> VM0:1234 **SYN packet arrives but no TCP handshake - no response**
- VM1:[random high port] -> VM0:[ssh] **Working**
- VM1 -> ping -> VM0 **Working**
- VM1 -> traceroute -> VM0 **Not working**

Behaviour when connecting from VM0 to VM1:

- VM0:[random high port] -> VM1:1234 **SYN packet arrives, TCP handshake happens as expected, connection OK**
- VM0:[random high port] -> VM1:[ssh] **Working**
- VM0 -> ping -> VM1 **Working**
- VM0 -> traceroute -> VM1 **Working**

The thing happening on port 1234 is happening with any other TCP port as well. Except for SSH. The web server is not reachable etc.

My stomach tells me, it's a firewall issue for some reason but it doesn't appear very logical to me. The machines are - virtually - connected via Layer 2 because they share the same bridge and there should be no Layer 2 firewall. Proxmox shouldn't interfere with the Layer 2 traffic as well (I guess?).

Their ARP records are correct and detected on the correct interface.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

PS:

There's the failing response to the SYN packet captured with wireshark (on all interfaces so wrong routing shouldn't be the reason)

[image: This is the capture on VM0 received via tcpdump -i any port 1234]

Comment: Could you please include the IP addresses used in the transactions in your post? My preliminary guess is that when you try to connect from VM1 to VM0 the IP address of one of the other interfaces is used (are you connecting using domain names?). If my guess is true, you need to include routes on VM1 that properly direct traffic toward the other two interfaces/networks as required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly I don't think, that it's a routing related issue due to the other TCP connections on the SSH port working properly on the exact same interface.

I'm connecting via IP addresses and the routing is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I lied when I stated that the machine had no other local firewall besides iptables enabled. The problem was nftables blocking my packets. I will never forget to check nftables again. :)

Check active nftables rules: `nft list ruleset`

Then either clear all nftables rules via `nft flush ruleset` or edit the `/etc/nftables.conf` (or the file where your nftables config is stored and open the port).

Finally `nft -f /etc/nftables.conf`